# Binding to a Datacontext of an ancestor

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datacontext

It would be best if showed you my code first and then ask the question:

```
<Window  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Drucker Typ" ItemsSource="{Binding Relative" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding PrinterType, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

I have the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and want to bind the `ItemsSource` to the `DataContext` of the Window and the `SelectedItem` to the current `ItemsSource` Object of the DataGrid.

How can this be done ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could explain what object-model you are trying the to bind to? You are trying to bind the column to the types of printers?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the ElementName where you have to be well aware of the NameScope you can also use FindAncestor. Here you define the Type of the parent object you want to bind to.

Example:

```
<TextBlock Text=”{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Text}” />
```

Comment: Tried this:

    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type main:DataBaseSettings}}, Path=PrinterTypes}" 

And got this

    System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Etikett_Creator.DataBaseSettings', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PrinterTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=48619823); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: tried this:
 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=PrinterTypes}"

 got this: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PrinterTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=3257321); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: try to use Path=DataContext.PrinterTypes

Comment: You need to specify that you are binding to the DataContext of object Window, and then your property name

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.PrinterTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=31473901); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Doesn't work either, think i've tried that already

Comment: Yes i've tried it with the type Window and the Type DataBaseSettings which is the type of my window! (Inherited from Window)

Answer (score 2):

Use an ElementName binding expression. This will allow you to reference the window by name from within the binding expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx

The usage is explained well here.

http://www.wpfdude.com/articles/BindingToElement.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work .. gave the window the name "wnd1" and then set the binding to:  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=wnd1, Path=PrinterTypes}" 

the corresponding error message: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=PrinterTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=40408429); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: This is because the binding expression is within a DataGrid column - I missed that. The other answer better fits your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<local:DataBaseSettings>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Drucker Typ" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataBaseSettings}}, Path=PrinterTypes}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding PrinterType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</local:DataBaseSettings>
```

Note that if each `Printer.PrinterType` does not directly reference an item that exists in your Window's DataContext, you need to overwrite the `.Equals()` method of your `PrinterType` class to make the two items equal.

Something like

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;


    PrinterType printerType= (PrinterType)obj;

    return (this.Id == printerType.Id);
}
```

Comment: Printertypes is just an ObservableCollection of strings!

Comment: @Raphi001 It's impossible for your Window's DataContext to be both a Collection of strings and a Class which contains a property called `Printers`. What properties exist on your Window's DataContext class? If it contains two properties, one a collection of `Printer` objects called `Printers`, and the other a collection of strings called `PrinterTypes`, you need to bind your ComboBox's ItemSource to `DataContext.PrinterTypes` (see my edit)

Comment: the datacontext of the window is the window itself, and this window contains 2 dependency properties. Printers, a collection of custom types, and printertypes, a string collection. I've tried to bind to the datacontext several times but it just doesn't seem to work, the error message says " cannot find source "

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.PrinterTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=20467445); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
"Etikett Creator.vshost.exe" (Verwaltet (v4.0.30319)): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll" geladen

Comment: @raphi011 The `Window` object does not contain a property called `PrinterTypes`. If this is a custom window, you need to bind to the RelativeSource of whatever your custom type is, then the property path of `PrinterTypes`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

for now i've found no other way to do this than setting the itemssource at runtime like this:

```
private void SetComboBoxItemssource()
    {
        PrinterTypes = database.GetPrinterTypes();

        DataGridComboBoxColumn cmbColumn = null;

        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dtaPrinters.Columns)
        {
            if ((cmbColumn = column as DataGridComboBoxColumn) != null)
                break;
        }
        if (cmbColumn == null)
            return;

        cmbColumn.ItemsSource = PrinterTypes;
    }
```

it works though ..

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get this working binding to a resource of the window:

```
<DataGridComboboxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PrinterTypes, Source={StaticResource MyDataContext}}" ... />
```

I cannot get it working with RelativeSources, FindAncestors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Just wanted to post it, because the answer I used was baked into the comments of fix_likes_codes's answer. The key is prefixing DataContext before the property name in the path.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```